# Traverse dom, next, prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the next slide element attr `href` after the active current one.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#slide01"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide02"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide03"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide04"></a></li>
</ul>
```

To get the current one I do

`slideActive = $('.nav li.active a').attr('href')` which is good it gives
`#slide02`, however I'm not sure how to get the `href` of the previous or next `li` elements.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  this:

1.for selecting the href of the next element

```
 $('.nav li.active').next('li').find('a').attr('href')
```

2.for selecting the href of the previous element

```
$('.nav li.active').prev('li').find('a').attr('href')
```